# What exactly is the purpose of msdata:Ordinal in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am looking at several XSD files that use msdata:Ordinal for the elements within a sequence. I can't seem to find anywhere what this is used and/or in what circumstances this would be needed. Can somebody help me out with an explanation and example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing. *.xsd files generated by [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or using [DataSet.WriteXmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexmlschema.aspx) tend to have this attribute, as defined in msdata.xsd in your "`<VS folder>\Microsoft Visual Studio *\Xml\Schemas`" folder:

```
...
    <xs:attribute name="Ordinal" type="xs:integer">
    </xs:attribute>
...
```

The attribute is used to define ordinal position of a column, which is useful for mapping the xsd schema to a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). 
See: [Deriving DataSet Relational Structure from XML Schema (XSD)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfdchewb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [Using XML in a DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84sxtbxh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[This article](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/xsd/chap1.htm) briefly talked about it:

> An extra attribute named Ordinal has been created. As always, it is a
>   part of the msdata space, with a value of 0 for the first column, and
>   1 for the second column. This is by virtue of each column being
>   assigned a number starting with zero and then, progressively
>   increasing it by one.